# Linux NASM Compiler doesn't compile "aaa"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nasm

Here's my current problem with NASM. I keep compiling this code right here but it just shows the error:

```
carry.asm:10: error: instruction not supported in 64-bit mode
```

Here is my code for this:

```
section .text
global main
main:
mov rsi, 4
mov rcx, 5
clc
add_loop:
mov al, [num1 + rsi]
mov al, [num2 + rsi]
aaa
pushf
or al, 30h
popf
mov [sum + rsi], al
dec rsi
loop add_loop
mov rdx, len
mov rcx, msg
mov rbx, 1
mov rax, 4
int 0x80

mov rdx, 5
mov rcx, sum
mov rbx, 1
mov rax, 4
int 0x80

mov rax, 1
int 0x80

section .data
msg db 'The sum is:', 0xa
len equ $- msg
num1 db '12345'
num2 db '23456'
sum db '     '
```

I can't seem to figure out what to do on this.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it as 32-bit?

Comment: `aaa` is not available in 64-bit mode http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/AAA.html . It should raise an exception if used.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have. It shows the "i386 architecture of input file `carry.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output"

Comment: @MichaelPetch What should I do?

Comment: You'd have to code it manually. The algorithm used is under the _Operation_ section in the link I provided in my first comment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you so much!